# How to loop through a string array and create multiple tables in Postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, loops, plpgsql

I would like to take a large table and break in up into smaller ones. I have the following code snippet which works by manually replacing `"NAME"` with the unique name in `ui00000bvbb.lad15nm`:

```
   CREATE TABLE "NAME" AS
   SELECT parcels_all_shapefile.* AS parcels
   FROM ui00000bvbb INNER JOIN parcels_all_shapefile ON ST_Intersects(ui00000bvbb.wkb_geometry, parcels_all_shapefile.wkb_geometry)
   WHERE ui00000bvbb.lad15nm = "NAME")
```

My question is how do I loop through a list of names and populate the above code? I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   m   varchar[];
   arr varchar[] := array[['Barnet'],['Westminster']];
BEGIN
   FOREACH m SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr
   LOOP
       CREATE TABLE m AS
       SELECT parcels_all_shapefile.* AS parcels
       FROM ui00000bvbb INNER JOIN parcels_all_shapefile ON ST_Intersects(ui00000bvbb.wkb_geometry, parcels_all_shapefile.wkb_geometry)
       WHERE ui00000bvbb.lad15nm = m)
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The loop variable should be just `text`. Use simple `FOREACH` loop (without `SLICE`) and dynamic SQL `EXECUTE` inside the loop:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    m   text;
    arr text[] := array['Barnet','Westminster'];
BEGIN
   FOREACH m IN ARRAY arr
   LOOP
        EXECUTE format($fmt$
            CREATE TABLE %1$I AS
            SELECT parcels_all_shapefile.* AS parcels
            FROM ui00000bvbb INNER JOIN parcels_all_shapefile ON ST_Intersects(ui00000bvbb.wkb_geometry, parcels_all_shapefile.wkb_geometry)
            WHERE ui00000bvbb.lad15nm = %1$L
        $fmt$, m);
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

Read also in the documentation:

- [Looping Through Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY)
- [Executing Dynamic Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)
- [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

Comment: `%1$I` should be `%I` and `%1$L` should be `%L` shouldn't it?